# Please help me with curl for downloading

Tags: curl

I am testing curl ftp to download from ftp site . I am using windows CMD

curl -u TEST:TEST "ftps://TEST.mysiteftp.com/Test" -o ~/Downloads/test1

Error
RETR response: 550

Answer (score 0):

The URL should contain ftp not ftps

wrong:
"ftps://TEST.mysiteftp.com/Test"

correct:
"ftp://TEST.mysiteftp.com/Test"

Also check your file permission on server. This happened to me when the permissions of the file on the ftp server were restrictive.

Comment: curl -u test:test "ftp://test.mysiteftp.com/TEST" -o ~/Downloads/test1 Error:curl: (67) Access denied: 530. I can download the file through filezilla and can access the file